# Store encrypted data, and retrieve it decrypted using Meteor and Mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor, boilerplate

I'm new to Meteor, I'm trying to build a simple application using [Pup](https://cleverbeagle.com/pup/v1/the-basics/settings).

I have a collection `Videos` and I have a property `url` in this collection. I want to store the `url` encrypted in the database. I'm wondering what's the best way to do so? where exactly should I hook my encrypt/decrypt logic?

I set the encrypted value in the autoValue hook of [simpleSchema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simpl-schema) as following:

```
url: {
  type: String,
  label: 'The url of the video.',
  autoValue() {
    return EncryptionHelper.encrypt(this.value);
  }
},
```

But can't find the place where I should decrypt it back.

Comment: What kind of db are you using? mysql? mongodb?

Comment: mongodb with simple-schema on top.

Comment: You can turn on encryption in mongodb itself and bypass the need to do it in your application logic.

Comment: You'll need to decrypt the value whenever you want to refer to it on the client. The trick is how you manage the decryption key(s).